# why $document.on('keydown') is one late?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keydown, onkeydown

I have a controller that injects `$document` to catch `keydown` event.
But this event is always one keypress late.

I have another method by using `$broadcast` from `ng-keydown` in `<body>` that works fine.

My question is : what is wrong with `$document.on('keydown', ...)`?

Here is a working example :

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-keydown="$broadcast('mykeydown', $event);">
   <div ng-controller="BroadcastController">
     key down by broadcast: {{keycode}}
   </div>
   <div ng-controller="KeyFromDocController">
     key down from $document : {{keycode}} <br>[always one late !!!]
   </div>
</body>

<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('BroadcastController', function($scope) {
    $scope.keycode = '?';
    $scope.$on('mykeydown',function(msg,evt) {
      $scope.keycode = evt.which;
    });
  })
  .controller('KeyFromDocController', function($scope,$document) {
    $scope.keycode = '?';
    $document.on('keydown',function(evt) {
      $scope.keycode = evt.which;
    });
  });
</script>
```

that you can test here [http://plnkr.co/edit/omhTiLi31BnEwrSwk75A](http://plnkr.co/edit/omhTiLi31BnEwrSwk75A?p=preview)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/kcVdNIQU1inAKPLj9RZH?p=preview The event is firing outside of the digest cycle. You "catch up" when you run it the second time, right before updating it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did this, **which you shouldn't**, it wouldn't be "one late" as you say:

```
  $document.on('keydown',function(evt) {
    $scope.keycode = evt.which;
    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

### [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjiTa6LXY6Dfqz3JfIAZ?p=preview)

In Angular you shouldn't be doing these kind of operations from a controler, but from a directive, DOM manipulation and DOM events belong to the directives, concretely to the `link` function of the directive.

What happens when you register an event like that  is that you are registering the event inside the controller, but when the event get's triggered angular doesn't know anything about that function, so you would have to call `$apply` in order to trigger the `$diggest` cycle that will re-evaluate and refresh the expressions of your view.